# How do I get ImageMagick installed

Tags: macos, imagemagick, paperclip

I decided to download the source and compile it locally and then run `sudo make install`.

However, when I try to run the command 'which ImageMagick' I don't see the path returned to the command line.

I am trying to get ImageMagick and Paperclip (for Rails 3) to play together nicely, but without being able to properly install it - Paperclip doesn't seem to work. The error I keep getting from Rails, when I do the following `has_attached_file :image, :styles => { :thumb => "64x64" }` is `Image Paperclip::CommandNotFoundError`

The output from the sudo make install was too large, so I posted it on Github here: https://gist.github.com/723339

Answer (score 5):

ImageMagick doesn't provide a binary named `ImageMagick` instead it has the 12 binarys named: `animate`, `compare`, `composite`, `conjure`, `convert`, `display`, `identify`, `import`, `mogrify`, `montage`, `stream`

which from that install log were installed, the important one: `convert` was installed at `/usr/local/bin/convert`

`convert` is the one that Paperclip uses and expect it to be on the `PATH` as line 61 of https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip/blob/master/lib/paperclip/thumbnail.rb reads

replacing `convert` with `/usr/local/bin/convert` at that line would fix it

Comment: Ok...so now my line 61 looks like this: `success = Paperclip.run("/usr/local/bin/convert", parameters, :source => "#{File.expand_path(src.path)}[0]", :dest => File.expand_path(dst.path))` I tried that, and it doesn't work. Also, if I wanted to do `:styles => { :medium => {200x200} }` would I have to edit another file also ? By doesn't work, I mean that it is giving me the same error and not resizing the file - with that change to line 61.

Comment: it seems that the source of that CommandNotFoundError error is run in https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip/blob/master/lib/paperclip/command_line.rb which is running the command via a method i can't make out

Comment: So what do you want me to do ?

Answer (score 3):

Why not slow it down slightly:

- As @DanD says, the result of ImageMagick installation is a series of binaries like `convert`, `stream`, etc.  From the Terminal you can check if they are in your `PATH` by doing:

  % which convert
  % which stream
  % which compare

If your installation has worked **AND** the location you have installed to is on your `PATH` then you will see the directory where the executables are located returned by the `which` command (which in your cases looks like it should be `/usr/local/bin`.

- If you run into problem here but think that the build was ok, then take a look at your path by doing:

  % echo $PATH

The output here is the places that are looked through when you type the name of a command (without an absolute path) at the command like (i.e. `ls`, `convert`, or anything like that).  If `/usr/local/bin` isn't there in your case you can add it in your profile by editing your `~/.profile` or `~/.bash_profile` file and adding the following line in your favourite text editor:

```
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/bin
```

Now, in terms of building the thing:

- Is there a configure step (i.e. something to run prior to `make`)?  If so, make sure you have selected the correct options.
- To make sure you're building it correctly why not try to make it first (just `make`), then test (`make test` if that rule exists) and then if everything is in good shape do your `make install`.

As for other ideas:

- If you are the only user on your Mac why not install it somewhere in your user space so you can more easily take a look at what is installed rather than dumping it into ~/usr/local`?
- You can also install via [`MacPorts`](https://www.macports.org/).  I know not everyone is a fan of this system, but once you install the Macports system installing ImageMagic can be as easy as `port instal ImageMagick`.  Macports will make the install (and any related dependencies) in `/opt` by default, so you may have to add `/opt/local/bin` to your `PATH` if you go this route as I described above.  Other alternatives to MacPorts are [fink](https://www.finkproject.org/) and [Homebrew](https://brew.sh/) but I'm not as familiar.